# Pls, recommend me an affordable robot for undergraduage course

Tags: ros, cram, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Are there any small robot platform under USD 4,000 that is suitable to run Knowrob and Cram-System ?
We are going to open a couple of projects for senior undergradute students at my class to build some experience with Knowrob and Cram-System.
Robots in http://wiki.ros.org/Robots are candidates but anyone out there recommend me one or two robots that may fit for our educational goals ?
PR2 and some other systems are too expensive for us, so, I am looking for a small and affordable system that might fit for our students.

Any robots running ROS meets minimum requirements to run Knowrob and Cram-system but not sufficient, aren't they ?

Thanks
Dongho

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201722/pls,-recommend-me-an-affordable-robot-for-undergraduage-course/) by [Dongho](https://answers.ros.org/users/21383/dongho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

turtlebot is the first thing that comes to my mind. You can just by the [kobuki](http://kobuki.yujinrobot.com/home-en/about/) base and then build the other parts off the shelf.

Another robot is the [oculus prime](http://www.xaxxon.com/oculusprime/shop). Its been recently announced and looks promising.

---

Originally posted by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) with karma: 654 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Especially if you'd like to use the systems for teaching, you do not need any special computing requirements. KnowRob, for instance, even runs on a Raspberry Pi (though it's not recommended). But any reasonable Linux-Computer should be enough.

As long as your system is well-integrated in ROS and uses the standard messages for e.g. navigation, you can easily add CRAM as executive. One (kind of) cheap robot that is said to be well-integrated with ROS is the [turtlebot](http://www.turtlebot.com/) for about 1200 Euro. In addition, you will need a cheap notebook that you can put on top.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2015-01-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dongho](https://answers.ros.org/users/21383/dongho/) on 2015-01-26**:
I appreciate you very much for your comments.